# Ionic market cannot find package

Tags: android, ionic-framework, google-play

I am trying to redirect the user to my android app to google playstore via [ionic market plugin](http://ionic-docs.herokuapp.com/docs/native/market) with cordova and it seems that it is not working.

**package.json:**

```
"@ionic-native/core": "^5.29.0",
"@ionic-native/market": "^5.36.0",
"cordova-plugin-market": "^1.2.0",
```

**method:**

```
  async openAppstoreEntry() {
    if (this.plt.is('android')) {
      try {
        let pkgn = 'com.biopix.pebble.ivd'
        let res = await this.market.open(pkgn);
        console.log(res) // ---> prints 'OK'
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e)
      }
    }
  }
```

When I click the button that calls the `openAppstoreEntry` on my android app the Google playstore throws:

> To view this content, install and set up a web browsing app.

Here is the app in Playstore:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.biopix.pebble.ivd&hl=en&gl=US

Comment: Were you trying to test it thru web? I think you need to test it using an actual device.

Comment: Hey Dave! I do test it in the android tv